# Regular expression not giving me expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am wanting to sort an array using regular expression such that after the array is sorted, all the dishes are included in results including both matched and unmatched ones. Currently only few matched ones are in the sorted array. If I have two words to be search in regular expression then it should search all the two words independently and finally get the matched items as well as unmatched items. If i search for 'Fish CUrry' then it should look for both words independently and get the results and also add all the unmatched results at the end of sorted array. Here unmatched is 'Biryani' and all other are matched.

```
let allDishes =     [
        {
            "DishId": 66,
            "DishName": "Fish CUrry",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 65,
            "DishName": "Fish CUrry Masala",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 64,
            "DishName": "Chilli Fish CUrry Masala",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 63,
            "DishName": "Mutton CUrry",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 62,
            "DishName": "Biryani",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        }
    ]
```

Below is the code that I have written:

```
let value = 'Fish CUrry';
let regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);
const sortedArr = allDishes 
                 .filter(x=>regex.test(x.DishName))
                 .sort((a, b) =>a.DishName.localeCompare(b.DishName));
```

Current result from above code is below:

```
[
    {
        "DishId": 66,
        "DishName": "Fish CUrry",
        "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
    },
    {
        "DishId": 65,
        "DishName": "Fish CUrry Masala",
        "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
    }
]
```

Expected sorted result needed should look like below:

```
[
        {
            "DishId": 66,
            "DishName": "Fish CUrry",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 65,
            "DishName": "Fish CUrry Masala",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 64,
            "DishName": "Chilli Fish CUrry Masala",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 63,
            "DishName": "Mutton CUrry",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        },
        {
            "DishId": 62,
            "DishName": "Biryani",
            "DateCreated": "2021-10-21T11:19:28.000Z",
        }
    ]
```

Comment: your regex looks for fish curry at the beginning of the string - `Chilli Fish CUrry Masala` doesn't start with `Fish Curry`, `Mutton CUrry` doesn't even contain the word `Fish Curry`, `Biryani` doesn't even LOOK like `fish curry` - do you know what filter does? do you know what sort does? I mean, the order you expect is made up, seems you want the order by id desccending, not by dishname

Comment: looking again, it seems your expected output === input - it seems you don't understand [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Sorry @Bravo, Am not so much experienced in Regular expression but I think you didn't understand the complete question. Another person below has understood it accurately and answer it. Thank you though for looking into it.

Comment: I understood the question perfectly well, I can see exactly what you wanted, because I can read. I posted a comment, a comment isn't an answer. I was merely pointing out what javascript concepts your code showed a misunderstanding of, if you read what those methods actually do, you may have figured out the solution yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler version of `allDishes` but it doesn't change the algorithm. First of all you want to find all dishes which contains any of word in sentence so you need in regexp replace all `space`s with `|` symbol. This symbol means `or` in regexp. Then I just firstly sort the given array and find all matched dishes. At the end from sorted array add all dishes which isn't in `resultArr`

```js
const allDishes =     [
        {
            "DishName": "Fish CUrry",
        },
        {
            "DishName": "Fish CUrry Masala",
        },
        {
            "DishName": "Mutton CUrry",
        },
        {
            "DishName": "Chilli Fish CUrry Masala",
        },
        {
            "DishName": "Biryani",
        }
    ];

allDishes.sort((a, b) => a.DishName.localeCompare(b.DishName));

const value = 'Fish CUrry'.replace(' ', '|');
const regex = new RegExp(`${value}`, `i`);
const resultArr = allDishes.filter(x => regex.test(x.DishName));

for (const dish of allDishes) {
    if (!resultArr.includes(dish)) resultArr.push(dish);
}

console.log(resultArr);
```

Comment: @aasirkhan Thank you! I removed `sortedArr` because we don't need it because `.sort()` change array inplace

Comment: ``const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);`` is suspicious because you only search for `Fish` at the start of the string, but for `CUrry` anywhere inside the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! I forgot about it when copy paste original code